# Special Numbers having only 2 and 5 as its digit

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers

A special number is a number which only consists of 2 and 5 as its digits, example- 2, 5, 22, 25, 52 ,555 etc. There is a function f(k) which returns the smallest number which is greater than or equal to k and is a special number.

My question is that provided two numbers L and R, we are required to find sum of f(k) where L<=k<=R. My approach of solving it in c++ is as follows:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long long int power(long long int a, long long int b)
{
    long long int prod = 1;
    for (long long int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
        prod *= a;
    return prod;
}

long long int f(long long int k)
{
    long long int nod = 0;
    long long int temp = 0, carry = 0;
    while (k)
    {
        if (k == 1)
        {
            temp = 0;
            for (int i = nod; i >= 0; i--)
                temp = temp * 10 + 2;
            return temp;
        }
        if (((k % 10) + carry) <= 2)
        {
            temp = 2 * power(10, nod) + temp;
            carry = 0;
        }
        if (((k % 10) + carry) > 2 && ((k % 10) + carry) <= 5)
        {

            temp = 5 * power(10, nod) + temp;
            carry = 0;
        }
        if (((k % 10) + carry) > 5 && ((k % 10) + carry) <= 9)
        {
            temp = 2 * power(10, nod) + temp;
            carry = 1;
        }
        k = k / 10;
        nod++;
    }

    if (carry == 1)
        temp = 2 * power(10, nod) + temp;

    k = temp;
    return k;
}

int main()
{
    long long int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        long long int l, r;
        cin >> l;
        cin >> r;
        long long int sum = 0;
        for (long long int i = l; i <= r; i++)
            sum += f(i);
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it is not working as expected and for many test cases it exceeds time limit. what can be the correct and optimal approach for this problem?

This question is from hackerearth.

https://www.hackerearth.com/pt-br/problem/algorithm/ozs-cool-numbers-a97d4b77-4f0585e3/#:~:text=Special%20numbers%20are%20positive%20integers,n%20d%20265%20are%20not.&text=For%20each%20test%20case%2C%20print%20the%20required%20answer.&text=Time%20Limit%3A%201%2C0%20sec,s)%20for%20each%20input%20file.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Is your code giving the wrong answer? crashing? slow? What do you want help with?

Comment: I edited the question. It takes very long time to solve problem.

Comment: What are the constraints of L and R ? What is time limit ? And what are the constrains for number of test cases per input file ? You need to provide as much information as you can

Comment: For two numbers `k` and `k + 1`, you're recalculating `f(k)` for each one from whole cloth. Figure out `f(k)` for a given `k`, then find out how many `k`s after this one share the same `f(k)` (how long until you hit a new special number) - that's one fiddly-bit calculation and one multiplication for each special number in the range.

Comment: What does the variable `nod` mean?

Comment: nod specifies digits position ex 24, for 4 nod = 0, for 2 nod =1

Comment: .for test case L = 12 and R = 47, the correct answer is 1461 but my code is giving answer 1721.

Comment: @jitesh why not call it digit?

Comment: nod (number of digit), I just named it that way

Comment: Thanks - just figuring it out. When someone posts their code from a competitive programming context the short variable names make it hard to debug.

Comment: yeah sorry for that, I just did not think about that

Comment: You can start by writing some test cases for `f(int k)` and seeing if that returns the correct number for each input. You should only need to  run through the first, say 56 numbers? to be reasonably sure it works.

Comment: yeah for numbers 43, 44, 45 it is giving 55 instead of 52 as its result

Comment: I feel my whole approach of solving this is problem is completely wrong

Answer (score 0):

I attempted this, and it seems to work. Pending peer review.

The general approach is to find the smallest special number that fits on top of your starting number, and then multiply this special number by the quantity of numbers until you hit the next special number. Since every number between two special numbers will map to the same special number, you only need to calculate each special number once per that range.

A 64 bit unsigned integer can represent a decimal number made up of only 2s and 5s of 19 digits maximum. Each search of the next special number is therefore logarithmic (base 2) in the number of decimal digits in the input number. The number of iterations of the sum loop is also logarithmic (base 2) in the number of decimal digits of the input number, making the total complexity `O(log 2N)`

1. Set `sum = 0`
2. Given the starting number `L`, set `next_k = L`
3. Find the smallest special number no less than `next_k`; `special = f(next_k)`
4. Set `k = next_k`
5. Set `next_k = min(special, R) + 1`. This is using the one-past-the-end idiom that is common in iterations
6. Set `distance = next_k - k`
7. `sum = sum + distance * special`
8. If `next_k <= R`, then go to 3.
9. Done. Return `sum`.

Of course, the question of how to "fit" a series of 2s and 5s on top of a given `k` needs to be answered. My approach was to start with the largest series of decimal 5s that can be represented in 64 bits (19 5's in a row).

1. Shift this 5-mask down by a factor of 10 until it's the same width as the input number
2. From the most significant digit, iterate through the digits and test if setting that digit to a 2 would still "fit" the input number. If so, twiddle it.

```
/*
A special number is a decimal number such that its
digits are only 2 or 5, e.g. {2, 5, 22, 25, 52, 55, ...}

Write a function, f( ), for any non-special number, k, that returns
the smallest special number that is greater than or equal to k

Given a range [L, R], find the sum of all f(k) for each k such
that L <= k <= R
*/

#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using value_t = unsigned long long;
static constexpr value_t MAX_FIVES = 5'555'555'555'555'555'555ull;
static constexpr value_t MAX_THREE_MASK = 3'000'000'000'000'000'000ull;

value_t least_special_no_less_than(value_t k)
{
    value_t special_number = MAX_FIVES;
    value_t three_mask = MAX_THREE_MASK;

    if (k == 0)
    {
        special_number = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        // shift the 555... mask down as low as it can go
        while (special_number / 10 >= k)
        {
            special_number /= 10;
            three_mask /= 10;
        }

        // twiddle each digit from 5->2 to fit the sheet onto the bed
        while (three_mask)
        {
            if (special_number - three_mask >= k)
                special_number -= three_mask;

            three_mask /= 10;
        }
    }

    return special_number;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "A special number is one with digits only 2 or 5, e.g. {2, 5, 22, 25, 55, 222, ...}\n"
        << "For a number, k, f(k) returns the lowest special number gte k\n"
        << "Enter two numbers L and R, this program calculates sum(f(k)) for all k s.t. L <= k <= R\n"
        << "\n"
        << "Enter L followed by R: ";

    value_t L, R;
    std::cin >> L >> R;

    value_t sum = 0;
    value_t k, next_k = L;
    std::cout << std::right
        << std::setw(20) << "k" << " "
        << std::setw(20) << "next_k" << " "
        << std::setw(20) << "special" << " "
        << std::setw(20) << "running sum" << " "
        << "\n";
    do
    {
        value_t special = least_special_no_less_than(next_k);
        k = next_k;
        next_k = std::min(special, R) + 1;

        sum += (next_k - k) * special;

        std::cout
            << std::setw(20) << k << " "
            << std::setw(20) << next_k << " "
            << std::setw(20) << special << " "
            << std::setw(20) << sum << " "
            << "\n";
    } while (next_k <= R);

    std::cout << std::left
        << "\nSum of all special numbers between [" << L << ", " << R << "]: "
        << sum << "\n";
}
```

This gives the following example output:

```
A special number is one with digits only 2 or 5, e.g. {2, 5, 22, 25, 55, 222, ...}
For a number, k, f(k) returns the lowest special number gte k
Enter two numbers L and R, this program calculates sum(f(k)) for all k s.t. L <= k <= R

Enter L followed by R: 12 47
                   k               next_k              special          running sum
                  12                   23                   22                  242
                  23                   26                   25                  317
                  26                   48                   52                 1461

Sum of all special numbers between [12, 47]: 1461
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the next special number at least equal to a given number, I would extract the decimal digits of that number. Then starting from the highest order digit:

- if a digit is greater than 5, then this one and all followings ones get value 2 and previous digit should be increased (beware if previous was 5, we need iterate, and if we are at first digit we need to add a new one)
- if a digit is 5, keep it and proceed to next one
- if 3 or 4, this one will be 5 and all following ones will be 2
- if 2, keep it and proceed to next one
- if 0 or 1, this one and all following ones will be 2

For efficiency reasons, I would compute that number, add it while the current number is less or equal and then compute next special number by increasing its least significant digit.

In the following code, I chose to encapsulate all special number processing in a class containing a vector of digit values and the number itself:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Special {
public:

    long val;
    std::vector<char> digits;

    // ctor builds first special number at least equal to val       
    Special(long val) {

        std::vector <char> d;
        int n=0;
        while (val > 0) {                // extract all decimal digits
            d.push_back(val % 10);
            val /= 10;
            n++;
        }
        digits = std::vector<char>(n, 2); // initialize the special number with 2
        // and start processing starting from most significant digit
        while (n-- > 0) {
            if (d[n] > 5) {
                digits[n] = 6;
                normalize(n);
                return;
            }
            else if (d[n] > 2) {
                digits[n] = 5;
                if (d[n] != 5) {
                    normalize(digits.size());
                    return;
                }
            }
            else {
                digits[n] = 2;
                if (d[n] != 2) {
                    normalize(digits.size());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        normalize(digits.size());
    }
    Special& normalize(int n) {
    /* compute the binary value, and process carries starting from nth digit */
        // First process carries
        int ndigits = digits.size();
        while (n < ndigits) {
            if (digits[n] > 5) {
                digits[n] = 2;
                if (n == ndigits - 1) {
                    digits.push_back(2);
                }
                else {
                    digits[n+1] += 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (digits[n] > 2) {
                    digits[n] = 5;
                }
                else {
                    digits[n] = 2;
                }
                break;
            }
            n++;
        }
        // compute the binary value
        val = 0;
        for (auto ix=digits.rbegin(); ix!= digits.rend(); ix++) {
            val = 10 * val + *ix;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Special& next() {
        /* increase to next special number */
        digits[0] += 1;       // just increase least significant digit
        return normalize(0);  // and normalize
    }
};

int main() {
    // read N
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    long l,r, tot;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        std::cin >> l >> r;
        tot = 0;
        Special s(l);
        while(l <= r) {
            if (l > s.val) s.next();
            tot += s.val;
            l += 1;
        }
        std::cout /* << l << " - " << r << " : " */ << tot << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's maybe late but I'm here to stay**

For this problem, the key is to recognize how the series work.
Having only **two** digits, 2 and 5, which mean the series would behave as

- 2 ---> create 22 and 25
- 5 ---> create 52 and 55
- 22 ---> create 222 and 225
- ...
- n ---> create (10n + 2) and (10n + 5) respectively

Below is my implementation for the problems using stack for further efficiency:

```
long long nthNiceNumber(int n) 
{
    queue<long long> q;
    q.push(2);  // init the stack with 2 and 5
    q.push(5);
    
    int nE = 2;    // means the back of the queue is the n^th element
    while (nE < n) // while doesn't reach the n^th element
    {
        q.push(q.front() * 10 + 2);
        nE++;
        
        if (nE == n) break;   // in one iteration, the queue will have 2 new 
                              // element,so if the first element appended is enough, break
        
        q.push(q.front() * 10 + 5);
        nE++;
        
        q.pop(); // pop the front of the queue that used to create two new element above, since it doesn't relevant anymore
    }
    int size = q.size();
    while (size-- > 1) q.pop(); // the n^th element always at the end of the queue, so pop until only one element left.
    return q.front();
}
```